Return from recursion
Hello in my program I need to implement a recursive descent and return from recursive calls. Input data (100, 37). I was able to print the recursive descent, but I do not understand how to print the return from recursive calls.

Descent:
In recursive descent, the first value is a, the second value is b.
100 37
200 18
400 9
800 4
1600 2
3200 1

Return from recursive calls:
Here first result, second a, fourth new_result. The third one is not needed yet.
3200
3200 1600 0 3200
3200 800 0 3200
3200 400 1 3600
3600 200 0 3600
3600 100 1 3700
3700


int rusMult(int a, int b)
{
    int res, ost, new_res;
    if (b < 0) 
    {
        rusMult(a, -b);
    }
    
    if(b == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (b > 0)
    {
        
        if (b % 2 == 0)
        {
            
            printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            return rusMult(a * 2, b / 2);
            //int res = rusMult(a * 2, b / 2);
            //printf("%d\n", res);
        }
        else
        {
            //int new_res = rusMult(a * 2, b / 2)+a;
            //printf("%d\n", new_res);
            //printf("%d\n", new_res);
            printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            return rusMult(a * 2, b / 2) + a;

        }
    }
    
}


When if (b < 0) is true, and you call rusMult(a, -b), what happens with the result that the call returns?

Besides that, what is the problem with your shown code? For some input, what is the expected result? What is the actual result? What is your question?

Sorry for the wait, I have now fully described the problem.

Capture the result of calling rusMult() recursively into a variable, do the printing (including the captured result), then return the captured result — int rv = rusMult(…); printf("…", …); return rv;

Note that 'recursive descent parsing' is a specific technique for parsing input data in things like compilers.  What you're doing is not recursive descent parsing, so the [tag:recursive-descent] tag is inappropriate.  I've removed it.

There are three recursive calls to rusMult.  Two of them return the result of the call.  One of them does not.  See if you can spot the difference.

Corner case: if (b < 0)  { rusMult(a, -b); ... leads to undefined behavior (like an infinite loop) when b ==INT_MIN.

@Евгений Смирнов, Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings to quickly receive a report about why if (b < 0)  {  rusMult(a, -b); } is a problem (no return value in that path).


In a function intended to return a computed value, always return a value. Change rusMult(a, -b); to return rusMult(a, -b);.

Reduce the code. Make it simple. Avoid introducing variables and nested conditions:


int rusMult(int a, int b)
{
    if (b < 0)
        return rusMult(a, -b);
    else if (b == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (b % 2 == 0)
        return rusMult(a*2, b/2);
    else
        return rusMult(a*2, b/2) + a;
}

Do not print in functions intended for computing, except for debugging or error reporting. Print the value returned by the function, not a value in the function:
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", rusMult(100, 37));
}


This is all good, of course, but the essence of the problem has not been solved.

@ЕвгенийСмирнов: None of the sentences in your post is a question (is an interrogative). You state you need “to implement a recursive descent.” The code in this answer does that. You state you need to “return from recursive calls.” The code in this answer does that. You state you “do not understand how to print the return from recursive calls.” The code in this answer does that. If there is some question you have that is not answered, you need to enter a new post that clearly and explicitly  states what the question is.

Thanks to everyone who took part in the discussion, I will continue to figure it out myself.

@ЕвгенийСмирнов It's not really supposed to be a discussion but a Q&A. You ask a specific question and hopefully get an answer to it, like in this case. You can of course ask more refined questions to solve the problem if your first attempt wasn't satisfactory.
